# LaserScan gives nan data to close round or sharp cornered objects

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quite new to this was toying with Turtlebot GMapping on ROS Kinetic when I encountered this error.

According to the topic description, any distance above 10 m will be referred to as nan. But while simulating, the msg.ranges[300], which refers to the front , gives nan value, especially if the object is round or has cylindrical surface.

I changed the logic, so that on such occurrence, it keeps rotating. But the RViz map gets severely distorted, as it estimates the value at infinity or very far. How do I fix that?

RViz map distortion: https://imgur.com/TXFw3qV
Node: https://imgur.com/mpQvbtY

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382281/laserscan-gives-nan-data-to-close-round-or-sharp-cornered-objects/) by [Yokai-](https://answers.ros.org/users/77595/yokai-/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-12**:
On http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping I see parameters `~maxRange` and `~maxUrange`. Have you set them to reasonable values?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-13**:
Also, could you please clarify if this is an issue with `gmapping` or if those are the actual values that get reported by your laserscanner? If yes, which laserscanner are you using (model, simulated)?

**Comment by [Yokai-](https://answers.ros.org/users/77595/yokai-/) on 2021-07-13**:
@Mike Scheutzow, I'm using the gmapping_demo provided by the turtlebot tutorial, which has a max range set to 80 m by default. But the issue is with LaserScan which gives the distance of very close round objects as nan (>10 m). Even if I'm not using the turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch file, the LaserScan alone gives faulty results

**Comment by [Yokai-](https://answers.ros.org/users/77595/yokai-/) on 2021-07-13**:
@mgruhler, I see no issue with GMapping, the LaserScan is providing faulty nan values. As for the laserscanner sensor used by the model is "360 Laser Distance Sensor LDS-01", according to https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/features/#features

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-13**:
I'm confused. Are you running in simulation (gazebo) or a real robot with a real sensor?

**Comment by [Yokai-](https://answers.ros.org/users/77595/yokai-/) on 2021-07-13**:
@mgruhler , sorry for not understanding earlier. It is a simulation.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-13**:
I have not run this particular simulation, but why are you surprised that a `nan` clears out the map up to 80 meters? You have told gmapping that the laser data is reliable out to that distance. Also, be aware that you can get `nan` in the real world because not every surface cleanly reflects the laser beam back to the lidar.

**Comment by [Yokai-](https://answers.ros.org/users/77595/yokai-/) on 2021-07-13**:
@Mike Scheutzow , I have no issues with nan clearing out the map. My issue is that the laserscan gives nan data for objects as close as 1 m from the robot, which is incorrect. This happens especially if the object is cylindrical. Maybe I failed to clarify my question. Sorry for that.

You can find the snap shot here : https://imgur.com/TXFw3qV

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-13**:
All lidars I'm familiar with also have a minimum distance. They do not work down to 0 meters. You would need to look at the simulation model to know how yours is configured.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-13**:
Please describe what you mean by "distortion". You first image is too small for me to make out the details, but it looks to me like the robot has not moved around that section enough to build up a good map. That cylindar adjacent to the robot is blocking a very big arc of the lidar scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All lidars have a minimum range. Objects closer than this distance usually return either 0 or NotANumber (nan).

To get optimal results, you must properly configure `gmapping` for the sensors you are using. Getting a `nan` sample from a lidar is normal and means "no light bounced back." `gmapping` will interpret this value as "no obstacles out to maximum range" for that ray.

If you move the robot to a new pose, it may then see an object that was previously not visible.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0